# Extracting polygon coordinates from only two specific corners

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates

**End goal:** To add two (or 4) fields to a polygon grid feature class which will contain coordinates of the lower left (southwest) and upper right (northeast) corners of each grid.

I have a feature class containing 40km grids (about 100 total polygons).  I realize that "*Feature Point to Verticies*" will output every corner for each grid but I only want the Northeast corner and the Southwest corner attributed to each polygon.

I'm thinking if there is a way to produce a unique attribute code for the output of each quadrant (another process to create quadrants within each grid poly?), I could then select the corners I want based off of the unique code.

Another method may be to generate xMin + yMin, for the lower left, and then xMax + Ymax? Could something work around this?

If there is an easier way of doing this that I'm missing here then please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a grid you gave the answer yourself... You can use the Xmin and Ymin calculations to create the coordinates of your needed points. To do this set the field calculator to python and paste into for example:

!shape.extent.XMax!

Left is Xmin/Ymin point right top Xmax/Ymax

Comment: Thanks!  I made this out to be much more complicated than it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will depend on your grid: how it was created, is it a regular grid of squares / rectangles, do they have same number of vertices, are they drawn in the same order etc?

I could see several options:

1. In case this is a regular, North-facing grid of squares or rectangles you could simply create a new grid of points starting at the lower left corner of the grid at a given interval corresponding to the size of your grid cells.
2. Calculate xMin and yMin for all grid cells using Field Calculator and Python, e.g.:

`!shape.extent.XMin!`

3. In case all grid cells have same number of vertices, you could probably also convert features to points and select every Nth point, starting from the first point representing lower left corner.

Probably some other ways will work as well... More info on how your grid is created would also help.